# Error when creating MySQL DB on Azure portal

Tags: mysql, azure, dreamspark

I have Microsoft Azure Dreamspark license and I'm trying to create free MySQL database, but everytime I choose plan etc. and press create button, I get error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH0CQ.png

Have you any ideas how to fix this error?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a support request for Azure

Comment: The status message in the error says 'The offer is not sold in the account market', so I would check for yourself that you are eligible for the free DB. Beyond that and as already mentioned above I think only MS support can help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

DreamSpark only includes the 1 free Clear DB database so you likely already have an existing MySQL database provisioned. Anything beyond that is a marketplace transaction and those are not covered by the DreamSpark Azure subscription benefits.

Comment: As far as I see, I don't have any of them. :|

Comment: If that is the case then there is something amiss with your account. I would open a "billing" support ticket and ask them to take a look.

Comment: What's the point of dreamspark then if just a free azure account provides the same stuff (web apps/mysql)?

Comment: Simple. A free Azure account expires in 30 days after that convert it to a paid account or all your stuff is lost. A DreamSpark subscription lasts for 12 months and can be renewed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Dreamspark on Azure offering are listed on www.dreamspark.com

Microsoft Azure for DreamSpark gets you started with the services you need to develop in the cloud at no cost:

•Azure App Service Web Apps is a part of a fully managed cloud offering that enables you to build and deploy web apps in seconds. Use ASP.NET, Java, PHP, Node.js or Python. Run popular web apps and CMS solutions. Set up continuous integration and deployment workflows with VSO, GitHub, TeamCity, Hudson or BitBucket – enabling you to automatically build, test and deploy your web app on each successful code check-in or integration tests.

•MySQL Database from ClearDB adds the power of MySQL to your Web Apps. With clearDB MySQL you can deploy more kinds of web apps and CMS solutions such as Wordpress, Joomla, Acquia Drupal, phpBB, and more.

•Application Insights provides a 360° view across availability, performance and usage of your ASP.NET services and mobile applications for Windows Phone, iOS and Android platforms. Search and analyze your data to continuously improve your application, prioritize future investments and improve overall customer experience.

•Visual Studio Online is the fastest and easiest way yet to plan, build, and ship software across a variety of platforms. Get up and running in minutes on our cloud infrastructure without having to install or configure a single server.

For help setting up your services check out the blogs at 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_student_developer_blog/